# Public transportation considerations for children in North Eastern USA

Tags: trains, public-transport, children, new-york-city, child-safety-seats

My wife and I will be going to Fairfield, CT in April with our 2 kids (2yo and 9mo), we might be going to NYC for a day or two.

My question comes with public transportation and the kids, I know if they need to go in a car the need to be properly seated in child seats, which makes me believe getting cabs is going to be a pain.

But moreover, are there any special considerations to think off to go on a bus, subway or train with them?

So far all I've found that to go in the subway, if we have strollers we need to pick up the kids and close the strollers to go into the sub, does this also apply for the MTA that goes from Fairfield to Grand Central?

What do I need to take into account (public transport wise) when traveling with small children to the USA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One would have to caveat the answer:  Laws regarding child safety in Cabs may vary from state to state but here goes:

[New York city](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/faq/faq_pass.shtml#9) officially exempts Cabs from requirement of Child Safety seats in [Massachusetts](http://www.livestrong.com/article/216354-taxi-child-safety-seat-laws/) you will need to restrain the child.

In [Buses](http://www.thecarseatlady.com/buses_and_trains/buses_and_trains.html) and commuter trains it is simply not possible to use a child safety seat at all as there is no equipment to secure it to the seat(in most buses).  Furthermore unless you want to pay for a separate seat your kids are allowed to ride in your lap.

Strollers: on trains and buses you will have to fold them and stow them away from the aisle.  On [Subway](http://www.mta.info/nyct/safety/) the situation is somewhat different.  Most parents I've seen leave the kids in strollers because there is no place to sit.  Most passengers are understanding to the situation.

One thing I would suggest is getting if you already don't have one is a [baby carrier](http://www.babybjorn.com/us/products/baby-carriers/comfort-carrier/comfort-carrier/) for your 9mo.

Comment: Massachusetts now exempts taxis as well. http://www.malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXIV/Chapter90/Section7AA

Comment: @choster http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60745-i48-k6257506-Taxis_and_Child_Car_Seats-Boston_Massachusetts.html - but only the driver of a cab is exempt apparently in the wonderful world of law....

Comment: So just to be 100% clear, it's perfectly legal for me to pick my child and seat him on my lap while on a taxi cab in NYC?

Comment: @rantsh That is exactly right.